# Partner Database for Saas application

Tags: database, saas

We want to build a SAAS product (Eg: Shopify, Salesforce etc)., where we will have different partners (Say, 500+ partners and 1 to 5 requests per second). Partners have different choices and preferences, but will have a fixed number of fields for their choices/ preferences (Eg: Do you want this? YES | Do you want that? No etc). All these preferences can be stored in one table. Altogether a partner will have (say) 20 tables.

Now I am looking for your suggestions - is it better to have individual database for each Partner as they Sign Up or should we maintain everything in a Single Database.

Comment: Very little information provided here. Some questions that are relevant to provide a good answer: how many partners are you expecting? What's the requests per second you're expecting per client?

Comment: I have modified the question.